# Hibernate: insert ManyToMany, generate ID in relationship table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let I have Tables (Books and Authors have ManyToMany relation ship)

**BOOKS**
id
book_name

**AUTHORS**
id
author_name

**BOOKS_AUTHORS**
id
book_id
author_id

I map this Tables on Entities

```
class Books  
{  
   @Id  
   long id;  

  @Column(name = "author_name")
   String name;


   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "BOOKS_AUTHORS", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))  
   List<Authots> authors;  

// setter, getters, adder  
}  

class Authors  
{  
   @Id  
   long id;  

   @Column(name = "author_name")
   String name;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "BOOKS_AUTHORS", 
              joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))  
   List<Books> books;  

// setter, getters, adder  
}
```

Now, I try do next

```
public void addAuthor(final String bookName, final Author author)
{  
      final Book book = // get book from database by bookName
      if (book == null)
         throw new DataNotFoundException("Book not found :(");
      author.addBook(book);
      book.addAuthor(author);  
      entityManager.persist(author);  
}
```

1) I get exception that ID of BOOKS_AUTHORS record must be not NULL
2) How I can Generate ID (ising sequance generator) for relationship-table BOOKS_AUTHORS

Comment: For this you can create tables with external script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use `@ManyToMany` to create join table with id field in it.

If id field in the join table is a requirement, you have to create a special entity class (such as `BookAuthor`) for that table and connect it with books and authors with `@ManyToOne`/`@OneToMany` relationships.

Otherwise you need to remove id field from `BOOKS_AUTHORS` table.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

If `books_authors` is not mapped using Hibernate, then use the database side auto id incrementor. Example:

```
ALTER table book_authors CHANGE id long NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: In this way I can generate ID for Author entity and for Book entity. But I need to generate ID for BOOKS_AUTHORS table, that isn't mapped

Comment: See edited version of my answer, book_authors needs its id auto increment at db side.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Projection](http://www.163jsp.com/help/hibernate32api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html)

```
                  session.CreateCriteria(typeof (BOOKS_AUTHORS))
                           .SetProjection(Projections.Max("Id"))
                           .UniqueResult()
```

and add to it +1 :) Sory its .net code im not familiar with java hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In **SpringBoot 1.5.3** and **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** you can use annotation `{@OrderColumn(name = "id")}`. For you example it should looks like:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinTable(name = "BOOKS_AUTHORS", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")) 
    @OrderColumn(name = "id")             
    List<Books> books;
```